# Asymptotic of countour integral with singularity

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I need to find the asymptotic of the integral
$$\int_0^{(1+)} \left[\frac{t(e^{-i\tau/n^2}-t)}{1-t}\right]^{in-\frac{1}{2}} dt, \quad n\to+\infty,$$

where the countour starts from $t=0$, goes around $t=1$ and ends in $t=0$.

The integrand has two saddle points $t_0=1\pm \sqrt{1-e^{-i\tau/n^2}} \sim 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{i \tau}}{n} \to 1$. Also $t=0$ is a singularity.
So, is it correct to apply, say, Laplace method summing over all contributions from saddle points? Or since of singularities the method of saddle point (deepest descent method, Laplace method) is incorrect here and some tricks should be done?

Comment: Isn't there an algebraic branch point at $t=1$?

Comment: I think we can say Yes and $1-t$ gets the multiplier $e^{2\pi i}$ after traversing the contour. The point $e^{-i\tau/n^2}$ which is near $t=1$ is not traversed around I think.

Comment: Additional question is that can intergating by parts such that it removes singularity in $t=0$ ($t^{-1/2}$ becomes $t^{1/2}$) make the problem easier?

Comment: Its hard to find a depeest descent route of integration...